# Google App Script - Can not insert group member

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a beginner ok... I'm trying to get multiple values of a cell `memberEmail`, then insert to mail group.
But I got an error is `Invalid Input: memberKey`.

```
var groupMail = 'test@gmail.com';
var listUserMails = [];
var userMails = JSON.stringify(sheet.getRange(4, 9).getValue());

listUserMails = userMails.split("\\n");

for (var i = 0; i < listUserMails.length; i++) {
  var userEmail = listUserMails[i];
  var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
  };
  member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupMail);
}
```

Update:
When I log value of an array `listMemberMails`, it seems that the array I received contains only 1 string. It's not the 3 strings as expected.

`["nguyen_tien_nghiep@gmail.com, nguyen_hai_ninh@gmail.com, vu_xuan_lam@gmail.com"]`

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/hMd1ckO"><a href="//imgur.com/a/hMd1ckO"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the JSON.stringify function. It assigns to the variable `userMails` the value

```
"nguyen_tien_nghiep@gmail.com\n nguyen_hai_ninh@gmail.com\n vu_xuan_lam@gmail.com"
```

whereby the doublequotes are considered part of the string. This is why, if you split userMails in three, it will give you the following three array entries:

```
listUserMails[0]:   "nguyen_tien_nghiep@gmail.com

listUserMails[1]:   nguyen_hai_ninh@gmail.com

listUserMails[2]:   vu_xuan_lam@gmail.com"
```

You can easily confirm the latter by adding `Logger.log(userEmail)` inside of your for-loop. This is what inhibits you from creating three members with a valid email address (since only the second entry is a valid email address.

With this being said if you replace

```
var userMails = JSON.stringify(sheet.getRange(4, 9).getValue());
```

with

```
var userMails = sheet.getRange(4, 9).getValue();
```

and then adjust the separator to "\n" instead of "\n" your code should work correctly.

As a suggestion, you can debug your code by  inserting logs (e.g. for `listUserMails.length`). This will help you to find errors.

Comment: Thank you for your help so much. I was confused about using the split function with "\n\n", then I was trying to use JSON.stringify. After I replace `var userMails = sheet.getRange(4, 9).getValue().split('\n')`, it work.